# How to decrypt AES encrypted values in mysql?

Tags: mysql, encryption, base64, aes

Below is my table in mysql:

```
desc user;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| randomname | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have inserted data in mysql with this query:

```
insert into user values(1,TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('MYNAME','ENCRYPTIONKEY')));
```

But I am not able to decrypt with the following query:

```
select AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(randomname),'ENCRYPTIONKEY') from user;
```

how can I decrypt here?

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: Your value is not *base64 encrypted*. Base64 is encoding, not encryption. Your value is actually **AES encrypted**. and the binary result of the encryption is **base64 encoded**. The wrong question for base54 decryption leads to confusion, as people now suggest answers about base64 decoding, which won't help.